# AVAudioEngine connect AVAudioUnitSampler after stop and start again crash

Tags: ios, objective-c++

help, AVAudioEngine attach and connect a AVAudioUnitSampler play is ok.but after call AVAudioEngine stop and start again, crash when play.
my code like:

```
    self.engine=[[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
    self.sampler= [AVAudioUnitSampler new];
    NSError *error=nil;

    NSURL soundfontFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"sf2"]];

    [_sampler loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL:soundfontFileURL program:0 bankMSB:0x79 bankLSB:0 error:&error];
    [self.engine attachNode:_sampler];
    [self.engine connect:_sampler to:[self.engine outputNode] format:nil];


    if([self.engine startAndReturnError:&error]){

            NSLog(@"start ok ");
    }else{

      NSLog(@"start err: %@",error);
    }

    //play at here is ok.
    //[_sampler startNote:60 withVelocity:100 onChannel:0];
    [self.engine stop];

    if([self.engine startAndReturnError:&error]){

            NSLog(@"start ok ");
    }else{

      NSLog(@"start err: %@",error);
    }

   //after stop and start again,play crash AudioStreamerImpl::sIOWorkerProcess (17)
   [_sampler startNote:60 withVelocity:100 onChannel:0];
```

crash info:
   libEmbeddedSystemAUs.dylib`DLSSample::GetMoreFrames:
   AudioStreamerImpl::sIOWorkerProcess (17): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x701c943f1a0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have such a problem in my app for months.
After some testing it looks like the crash does not appear when you reload your SoundFont between starting the engine and playing a note.

```
    engine.stop()
    do {
        try engine.start()
        reloadSoundFont() // remove this, and there will be the crash with GetMoreFrames()
    } catch {
        print("Could not start engine: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    self.sampler.startNote(60, withVelocity: 100, onChannel: 0)

    delay(1.0) {
        self.sampler.stopNote(60, onChannel: 0)
    }
```

Comment: OMG! it's works! I thought i need reconnect node to engine when reloadSoundFont but it didn't need.